# android studio is taking too long time to build

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android and android studio is taking too long to build
and I'm[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5HRd.png) not sure why

Comment: File -> Sync project with Gradle files

Comment: You haven't built the project yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that sometimes Android Studio builds either get stuck or slow down for seemingly no reason. First thing to try would be to quit Android Studio, then run `./gradlew --stop` from the command line to make sure any Gradle deamons have been shut down completely. You may also want to do a `./gradlew clean` to get rid of any intermediate files that might be troubling the build.

If that doesn't help, you may need to look into optimizing your build. There are lots of resources on the web, but you might want to start with the [Android team's list of ideas](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build).